# Configuring IIS SSL for PCI

Tags: tls, pci-dss, iis

Is there a clear, concise list of of SSL settings available for IIS which will pass my PCI audit scanning?

Preferably something for both IIS 6 and IIS 7

I'm currently running into BEAST issues but I'm hoping that the answers here will be more general  and a good resource for anyone needing to deal with IIS and PCI. Maybe even a canonical question. :)

I've had to piece together a list of ciphers and protocols to disable, some IIS 7 prioritization options, etc. I know it could be improved on.

Comment: check the answer here http://serverfault.com/q/103058/95089

Answer (score 1):

Clear and concise for PCI audit? No problem, as of now, enable SSL 3.0, disable the rest.

But you also want something more general and you want to combat BEAST? That makes things no longer clear or concise.

There are multiple lists, including [some](http://www.justfen.com/post/22121613280/pci-iis7-5-beast-vulnerability-donendusted) that include handy powershell scripts to do it for you.